# HashMap with Object Key

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have created a `HashMap` with Object as Key and String as Value. I am facing issue when I assign a new Object with same account number(which is unique key) and I haven't inserted in to my `HashMap` and if I am getting it, old value gets returned instead of null. I am new to Java `HashMap` internal working.

```
class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
           HashMap<Account, String> map = new HashMap<Account, String>();  
            Account a1 = new Account(1);
            a1.setHolderName("A_ONE");
           Account a2 = new Account(2);
            a2.setHolderName("A_TWO");
            map.put(a1, a1.getHolderName());
            map.put(a2, a2.getHolderName());
            a1.setHolderName("Defaulter");
            a2.setHolderName("Bankrupt");
            System.out.println(map.get(a1)); //Prints A_ONE
            System.out.println(map.get(a2)); //Prints A_TWO
            Account a3 = new Account(1);
            a3.setHolderName("A_THREE");
            System.out.println(map.get(a3)); //Prints value of a1 ??? WHY SO
      }
    }

    public class Account
    {
        private int accountNumber;
        private String holderName;

        public Account(int accountNumber) {
            this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        }

        public String getHolderName() {
            return holderName;
        }

        public void setHolderName(String holderName) {
            this.holderName = holderName;
        }

        public int getAccountNumber() {
            return accountNumber;
        }

        //Depends only on account number
        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            final int prime = 31;
            int result = 13;
            result = prime * result + accountNumber; 
            return result;
        }

        //Compare only account numbers
        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Account other = (Account) obj;
            if (accountNumber != other.accountNumber)
                return false;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Expectation- `map.get(a3)` should be `null`

Comment: You are inserting it to hashmap. `map.put(a1, a1.getHolderName());` this line will insert a1 object and a1.getHolderName() string to hashmap.

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Comment: @BasilBourque I upvoted your comment but you could’ve fixed it yourself

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar I have edited many title, for a specific technical tweak or add words for future searching. But writing a descriptive title is the job of the author, not the reader. In addition, here we have a newbie with a rep of 1, so we should be politely guiding them to practice successful use of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Look at your `hashCode` method; as your own comment already says: *Depends only on account number* and look at your `equals` method; as your own comment already says: *Compare only account numbers*. So you did all necessary steps to ensure that two `Account` instances are considered equal if they have the same account number and now you’re surprised that `HashMap` considers the two `Account` instances with the same account number equal…

Answer (score 0):

Its not lead to your expectation because, Overridden of equals method seek holder name to test.

try with below method,

```
 @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Account)) {
            return false;
        }
        Account user = (Account) o;
        return user.accountNumber == accountNumber &&                   
                user.holderName.equals(holderName);
    }
```

You need to take care of certain points while you are overriding hash code and equals method. You can read more on https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-overrides-equals-and-hashcode/

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Any reasonable implementation of `Map` (not only `HashMap`) will give you this result. A `Map` stores pairs of keys änd values. When you `get` the value for a key, it looks if one of the stored keys is equal to the given keys and gives you the corresponding value. According to your definition of `Map`, `a1` and `a3` are equal. So when you do `map.get(a3)` you get the value of `a3`.

Besides this it is not a good idea to update a key after using it in a `Map`. Although it is not a real problem here, it can produce unpredictable results if you update fields that are used in the methods `hashCode` and `equals`.

What you have well done: You have overridden `equals` and `hashCode` consistently.